# Heroes 3 Complete - cheat without cheating

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-3

Could anyone please explain how cheat mechanism works?

When playing original homm3 campaign:

The first campaign I used:

`nwctheconstruct` - for TP check in magic guild and reload back to precheat save

`nwcwhatisthematrix` - to lookup map in reload back to precheat save

I successfully finished campaign and got rank in a table and not labelled as a cheater.

The second campaign (inferno / dungeon) I used:

Same as in first plus `nwcneo` and reload back to check the path to earth magic on a hero.

By the end of dungeon/inferno campaign I was labelled as a cheater.

Then I replayed this campaign without using `nwcneo` but with two as in first.

I still got labelled as cheater?!

Then I continued and went to play rampart/ stronghold campaign and completed it clean - without any cheat look ups and reloads AND STILL got labelled as a cheater.

I don't understand the mechanics of this.

I know that some cheat codes like the one making all buildings complete are transient and affecting save after reload - like the buildings are still built after reload to untainted save so I am suspecting `nwcneo` is corrupting entire campaign save or first campaign is lenient on cheat look ups?

Could anyone please help figure out this? Or those privy to code modders.

I used `nwcwhatisthematrix` and `nwctheconstruct` and `nwcoracle` on individual scenarios and never got labelled as a cheater in the rank. I never used `nwcneo` in individual scenarios.

For moral dwellers I simply want as best play score as I can and don't want to be harassed by RNG which which thinks "holy prayer" "summon water elemental" and "water walking" must come up 70 percent of time.

Comment: I created simple scenario map and tested "nwcneo" reload... And it didn't blame me as cheater... This is truly mysterious...